# how i can enable TLS before calling .exe inside PS1 file

Tags: powershell, exe, tls1.2, tls1.3, servicepointmanager

I have a ps1 file which calls a .exe, as follow:-

```
Show-Message -Message "Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it" 
& "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.exe" "true" $Username $Password
```

now this will raise the following exception:-

```
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Stacktrace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.Common.ConfigureSharePointContext.ConfigureClientContext(String url, String userId, String password)
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.Program.AddGroups(Dictionary`2 listval, List`1 groupData)
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Stacktrace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.Common.ConfigureSharePointContext.ConfigureClientContext(String url, String userId, String password)
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.Program.DeleteGroups(Dictionary`2 listval, List`1 groupData)
17/06/2022 19:51:04 - Creating group and adding users to it failed
```

I read many articles which mentioned that this error can be resolved by enabling TLS as mentioned in this link @ https://blog.darrenjrobinson.com/powershell-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send/, where they mention  :-

*Add the following line before your Invoke-RestMethod or Invoke-WebRequest call;
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor
[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12*

but in my case i can not modify the .exe file, so how i can add the above in the exe or before calling the .exe?

I tried running this , before calling the PS1 file, but got the exact error , as follow:-

```
PS C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\deployments\Scripts\Helper Utilities> cd C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\deployments\Scripts\
PS C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\deployments\Scripts> $TLS12Protocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType] 'Ssl3 , Tls12'
PS C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\deployments\Scripts> [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $TLS12Protocol
PS C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\deployments\Scripts> .\Deploy.ps1
18/06/2022 12:13:31 - Running with full privileges
18/06/2022 12:13:31 - Starting scripts at: 06/18/2022 12:13:31
18/06/2022 12:13:31 - Clearing all the previous logs...
18/06/2022 12:13:31 - All previous logs cleared
18/06/2022 12:13:31 - Adding SharePoint libraries...
18/06/2022 12:13:31 - Added SharePoint libraries
18/06/2022 12:13:31 - Adding common library functions
18/06/2022 12:13:31 - Added common library functions
18/06/2022 12:13:56 -
18/06/2022 12:13:56 - Running Pre-requisites check...
18/06/2022 12:13:56 -
18/06/2022 12:13:56 - Checking Excel file existence
18/06/2022 12:13:56 - C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\deployments\MCDeploymentConfig.xlsx
18/06/2022 12:13:56 - Configuration Excel file exists
18/06/2022 12:13:56 - Reading parameters from Excel file...
18/06/2022 12:13:56 - All the parameters are retrieved successfully
18/06/2022 12:13:56 -
18/06/2022 12:13:56 - Running .NET Framework check...
18/06/2022 12:13:56 - .NET Framework Version 4.0 or greater exists
18/06/2022 12:13:56 -
18/06/2022 12:13:56 - Running SharePoint Version check for https://mellowsolutionsgmbh.sharepoint.com...
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - SharePoint Version is: 16.0.0.22601
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - Current SharePoint version is 2013
18/06/2022 12:13:58 -
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - Running check for SharePoint Online library...
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - PowerShell SharePoint Online library is present
18/06/2022 12:13:58 -
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - Running check for Azure PowerShell...
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - Azure PowerShell is present
18/06/2022 12:13:58 -
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - Running check for Workflow Service Application Check...
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - Starting deployment...
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - adminupwork@MellowSolutionsGmbH.onmicrosoft.com
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - Xoq92450@@
18/06/2022 12:13:58 - Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Stacktrace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.Common.ConfigureSharePointContext.ConfigureClientContext(String url, String userId, String password)
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.Program.AddGroups(Dictionary`2 listval, List`1 groupData)
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Stacktrace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.Common.ConfigureSharePointContext.ConfigureClientContext(String url, String userId, String password)
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.Program.DeleteGroups(Dictionary`2 listval, List`1 groupData)
18/06/2022 12:14:00 - Creating group and adding users to it failed
```

Here is the Deploy.ps1 file i am trying to run:-

```
#----------------------------------------------
# Steps performed in this script:
#
# Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it
# Step 1b: Create configuration lists
# Step 2: Create taxonomy hierarchy
# Step 3: Create site columns and content types
# Step 4: Update search configuration file and upload to SharePoint
# Step 5: Activate SharePoint Server Publishing infrastructure feature on catalog site collection 
# Step 6: Creating Site Collection(s)
# Step 7: Update site collection view with field(s)
# Step 8: Create ProvisionMatterList
# Any changes in these steps, kindly update this list. Also update the checkpoint in Revert script
#----------------------------------------------

# The below section would start new PowerShell in elevated mode
param([switch]$Elevated)

function Test-Admin {
  $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
  $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

# Get the current directory of the script
Function ScriptRoot {Split-Path $MyInvocation.ScriptName}
$ScriptDirectory = (ScriptRoot)

# Get the parent directory of the script
Function Get-ParentDirectory {Split-Path -Parent(Split-Path $MyInvocation.ScriptName)}
$ParentDirectory = (Get-ParentDirectory)

# Global Variables to be used throughout the scripts
#Set Excel file path
$ExcelFilePath = "$ParentDirectory\MCDeploymentConfig.xlsx"

#Create Log folder if not exist
$LogFolder = "$ScriptDirectory\Logs"
If (-not (Test-Path -Path $LogFolder -PathType Container))
{ 
   New-Item -Path $LogFolder -ItemType directory -Force 
}

# Set error log file path
$ErrorLogFile = "$ScriptDirectory\Logs\ErrorLog.txt"

# Set log file path
$LogFile = "$ScriptDirectory\Logs\Log.txt"

# Change log file name if already present
If (Test-Path $LogFile) {
    $timestamp = Get-Date -format "dd_MMM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss"
    $LogFile = "$ScriptDirectory\Logs\Log_$timestamp.txt"
}

# Set revert log file path
$RevertLogFile = "$ScriptDirectory\Logs\RevertLog.txt"

# Set helper utilities folder path
$HelperPath = "$ScriptDirectory\Helper Utilities"

Set-Location $ScriptDirectory

# Message Types 
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   public enum MessageType
   {
      Success,
      Warning,
      Failure
   }
"@

# Function to display message on console
Function Show-Message([string] $Message, [string] $Type, [bool] $Newline = $true)
{
    $timestamp = Get-Date -Format G
    $Message = $timestamp + " - " + $Message
    switch ($Type)
    {
        ([MessageType]::Success)
        { 
        if($Newline) {
            Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor Green
           }
           else {
            Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
           }
        }
        ([MessageType]::Warning) 
        { 
            if($Newline) {
                Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor Yellow     
            }
            else {
                Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
            }
        }
        ([MessageType]::Failure)
        {
            if($Newline) { 
                Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor Red 
            }
            else {
                Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline
            }
        }
        Default { Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor White }
    }
    # Write into log file
    if(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Message)) {
        ($Message) | Out-File $LogFile -Append
    }
}

if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) 
    {
        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting
        Show-Message -message "Elevation of privileges did not work, Aborting!" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)

    } 
    else {
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    }
    exit
}
Show-Message -Message "Running with full privileges"

$Date = Get-Date
Show-Message -Message "Starting scripts at: $Date" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)



Function RevertAll($ScriptDirectory, $Checkpoint) {
        . "$ScriptDirectory\Revert.ps1" -Checkpoint: $Checkpoint -ScriptDirectory: $ScriptDirectory
}

#----------------------------------------------
# Clear all existing logs from error file or creates a new file
#----------------------------------------------

Show-Message -Message "Clearing all the previous logs..." -Type ([MessageType]::Warning)

"" | Out-File $ErrorLogFile
Clear-Content $ErrorLogFile

"" | Out-File $RevertLogFile
Clear-Content $RevertLogFile

Show-Message -Message "All previous logs cleared" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)

#----------------------------------------------
# Add SharePoint Client DLLs
#----------------------------------------------
Show-Message -Message "Adding SharePoint libraries..." -Type ([MessageType]::Warning)
if ((Test-Path -Path "$HelperPath\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll") -and (Test-Path -Path "$HelperPath\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll") -and (Test-Path -Path "$HelperPath\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll")) {
    Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$HelperPath\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
    Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$HelperPath\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")
    Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$HelperPath\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll")
    Show-Message -Message "Added SharePoint libraries" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
}
else {
    Write-Log $ErrorLogFile "Unable to load SharePoint libraries..."
    return $false
}

#----------------------------------------------
# Include Common functions script
#----------------------------------------------

Show-Message -Message "Adding common library functions" -Type ([MessageType]::Warning)
. "$ScriptDirectory\LibraryFunctions.ps1"
Show-Message -Message "Added common library functions" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)

#----------------------------------------------
# Accept required credentials for deployment
#----------------------------------------------

$SPCredential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter credentials to access SharePoint tenant."

If ($Null -eq $SPCredential) {
    # Display error message and exit
    Write-Log $ErrorLogFile "Failed to get credentials"
    return
}

#----------------------------------------------
# Run Pre-requisite checker
#----------------------------------------------

Show-Message -Message ""
. "$ScriptDirectory\PreRequisitesScript.ps1"

$ExcelValues = (Read-FromExcel $ExcelFilePath "Config" ("TenantURL", "TenantAdminURL", "CatalogSiteURL") $ErrorLogFile)
$ExcelValues = $ExcelValues.Split(";")
if($ExcelValues.length -le 0)
{
    Write-Log $ErrorLogFile "Error reading values from Excel file. Aborting!"
    return $false
}
$TenantUrl = $ExcelValues[0]
$TenantAdminURL=$ExcelValues[1]
$CatalogSiteUrl=$ExcelValues[2]
$Username = $SPCredential.UserName
$Password = $SPCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

if($IsValid -eq $true)
{
    Show-Message -Message "Starting deployment..."
    Show-Message -Message $Username 
    Show-Message -Message $Password

    # Setting current location to "Helper Utilities" folder, in order to run the utility applications
    cd $HelperPath
    #----------------------------------------------
    # Create configuration lists in central repository in SharePoint
    #----------------------------------------------

    Show-Message -Message "Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it" 
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.exe" "true" $Username $Password

    If ((Get-Content $ErrorLogFile) -ne $Null) {
        Show-Message -Message "Creating group and adding users to it failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
        RevertAll $ScriptDirectory 1
        return
    }
    else {
        Show-Message -Message "Completed creating groups and adding users to it" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
    }   
    #----------------------------------------------
    # Create configuration lists in central repository in SharePoint
    #----------------------------------------------
    
    Show-Message -Message "Step 1b: Create configuration lists" 
    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.ConfigureLists.exe" "false" $Username $Password

    If ((Get-Content $ErrorLogFile) -ne $Null) {
        Show-Message -Message "Creating configuration lists failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
        RevertAll $ScriptDirectory 1
        return
    }
    else {
        Show-Message -Message "Completed creating configuration lists" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
    }
    

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Configure Taxonomy hierarchy in SharePoint
    #----------------------------------------------
    Show-Message -Message "Step 2: Create taxonomy hierarchy" 
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateTerm.exe" "false" $Username $Password
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateTerm.exe" "true" $Username $Password
    
    If ((Get-Content $ErrorLogFile) -ne $Null) {
        Show-Message -Message "Creating taxonomy hierarchy failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
        RevertAll $ScriptDirectory 2
        return
    }
    else {
        Show-Message -Message "Completed creating taxonomy hierarchy" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
    }
    

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Create Site Columns and Content Types
    #----------------------------------------------

    Show-Message -Message "Step 3: Create site columns and content types"
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateSiteColumns.exe" "false" $Username $Password
 
    If ((Get-Content $ErrorLogFile) -ne $Null) {
        Show-Message -Message "Creating site columns and content types failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
        RevertAll $ScriptDirectory 3
        return
    }
    else {
        Show-Message -Message "Completed creating site columns and content types" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
    }
     
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateContentTypes.exe" "true" $Username $Password
    If ((Get-Content $ErrorLogFile) -ne $Null) {
        Show-Message -Message "Creating content types failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
        return
    }
    else {
        Show-Message -Message "Completed creating content types" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
    }

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Update search configuration file and upload to SharePoint
    #----------------------------------------------
    Show-Message -Message "Step 4: Update Search Configuration files and upload to SharePoint"
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.UpdateAppConfig.exe" "3" $Username $Password "false"
        
    If ((Get-Content $ErrorLogFile) -ne $Null) {
        Show-Message -Message "Updating Search Configuration failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
        RevertAll $ScriptDirectory 4        #Revert from step 3 to 1
        return
    }
    else {
        Show-Message -Message "Completed updating search configuration file" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
    }

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure
    #----------------------------------------------
    Show-Message -Message "Step 5: Activating SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure at Catalog site collection"
    try 
    {
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($CatalogSiteUrl)  
        $Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $SPCredential.Password)   
        Show-Message -Message "Enabling the Feature with GUID" $PublishingFeatureGuid
        $FeatureGuid = [System.Guid] $PublishingFeatureGuid
        $SpoSite = $Context.Site 
        $SpoSite.Features.Add($FeatureGuid, $True, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None) 
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        Show-Message -Message "Activated SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure Feature" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
    }
    catch [System.Exception]
    {
        Show-Message -Message "Could not activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature." -Type ([MessageType]::Warning)
        #Write-Log $ErrorLogFile $_.Exception.ToString()
    }
    finally {
        $Context.Dispose()
    }
   
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Create site collection(s) on SharePoint library
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Connect-SPOService -url $TenantAdminUrl -Credential $SPCredential
    $Rootsite = Get-SPOSite($TenantUrl)
    $ReturnedValue = [string[]]$Rootsite.DenyAddAndCustomizePages
    If("false" -ne $ReturnedValue.ToLower())
    {
        Set-SPOSite -Identity $TenantUrl -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false
    }
    
    Show-Message -Message "Step 6: Creating Site Collection(s)"
    . "$ScriptDirectory\CreateSiteCollection.ps1" -Username: $Username -Password $Password
    If ((Get-Content $ErrorLogFile) -ne $Null) {
        Show-Message -Message "Creating site collection failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
    }
    else {
        Show-Message -Message "Completed creating site collection" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
    }

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Update site pages view with fields
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Show-Message -Message "Step 7: Update site collection view with fields"
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.UpdateView.exe" $Username $Password

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Complete tool error check
    #----------------------------------------------
    If ((Get-Content $ErrorLogFile) -eq $Null) {
        Show-Message -Message "Update site collection view with fields successfully" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
    }
    else {
        Show-Message -Message "Update site collection view with fields failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
    }
    
    
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Create Provision Matter List
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Show-Message -Message "Step 8: Create Provision Matter List"
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.UpdateListPermissions" $Username $Password

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Complete tool error check
    #----------------------------------------------
    If ((Get-Content $ErrorLogFile) -eq $Null) {
        Show-Message -Message "Deployment completed successfully" -Type ([MessageType]::Success)
    }
    else {
        Show-Message -Message "Deployment failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
    }
    
}
else
{
    Show-Message -Message ""
    Show-Message -Message "Deployment failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
}

$Date = Get-Date
Show-Message -Message "Ended Deployment at: $Date"
```

Thanks

Comment: Because the [github](https://github.com/microsoft/mattercenter) is 6 years old, I think you need to wait for someone, with actual knowledge about MasterCenter, to fix the issue you (also) created there: https://github.com/microsoft/mattercenter/issues/870,   and asked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/894264/running-deployps1-when-trying-to-install-httpsgith.html

Comment: @Luuk yes posted on multiple forums ,, but did not get any help

Comment: You might need to anble TLS 1.2 on the client (see: [How to enable TLS 1.2 on clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client)), because, as far as I can see, the application tries to connect to Sharepoint, not specifying anythiing special (just url, userid, password) (see: [source](https://github.com/microsoft/mattercenter/blob/master/tree/master/cloud/src/Helper%20Utilities/Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.HelperUtilities/Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.Common/ConfigureClientContext.cs))

Comment: @Luuk thanks and is what i need by adding `PS C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\deployments\Scripts> $TLS12Protocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType] 'Ssl3 , Tls12'
PS C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\deployments\Scripts> [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $TLS12Protocol` before running the .ps1 file the correct way to enable TLS2.1?

Comment: I think those settings only apply to your powershell environment, and not to the process that is started from powershell. (But I am not sure about this!) The connection create by the application has it's own `SecurityProtocol`). A Safer way, which should work is adding the registry keys mentioned on the link (see earlier comment), because that should change the default SecurityProtocol used.

Comment: @Luuk yes i added the register key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp`  but i can not find this `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp\`  as there is no folder named `WinHttp` under `internet settings`... and i restarted my windows 10 but still the script will raise the same error.. do u have any idea?

Comment: the article has a link to [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392), which has a link to [easy fix](https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/6/5/0658B1A7-6D2E-474F-BC2C-D69E5B9E9A68/MicrosoftEasyFix51044.msi). This easy fix does not work on Windows 11 (and probably also not on Windows 10).  So, it might be better to wait for an answer from someone with more experience in SharePoint.

Comment: @Luuk i already posted on GitHub but seems there are no recent activities on this solution,,, so i directly emailed the 3 contributors  , got a delivery failure already from one email,, so i am waiting for a response from them either by email or on gitHub.. anyway i really appreciate the help you provided so far.. thanks