# '[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 ;\UpdateView.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I have the following inside my Power Shell PS1 file, to set Tls12 + call .exe :-

```
Show-Message -Message "Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it" 
    & "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; $HelperPath\UpdateView.exe" "true" $Username $Password

    If ((Get-Content $ErrorLogFile) -ne $Null) {
        Show-Message -Message "Creating group and adding users to it failed" -Type ([MessageType]::Failure)
        RevertAll $ScriptDirectory 1
        return
    }
```

but i am getting this error:-

```
& : The term '[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
\UpdateView.exe' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\deployments\Scripts\Deploy.ps1:352 char:7
+     & "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityPro ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ([Net.ServicePoi....UpdateView.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

any advice please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how i can enable TLS before calling .exe inside PS1 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72668081/how-i-can-enable-tls-before-calling-exe-inside-ps1-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) takes a command / executable *name* / *path* only as an argument, not *whole statements*.

(While it can also accept a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) `{ ... }` containing one or more full statements, there's no need for it here, though you can generally use it to create a *child scope*).

Simply execute the two statements in sequence:

```
# Set the protocol (an assignment statement)
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# Call the executable (a command call).
& $HelperPath\UpdateView.exe" true $Username $Password
```